# matlab mnrfit warning: "Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled"

Tags: matlab

I'm using MATLAB's [`mnrfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mnrfit.html?nocookie=true) to perform multivariate binomial logistic regression. My inputs are an `n x p` matrix, `X`, with observations as rows and predictors as columns (there are no missed observations/NaNs), and an `n x 1` column vector of labels, `Y`, indicating the class as either "1" or "2."

Originally, I got an error message for a singular matrix, so I went through `X` and

- removed columns containing all 1's or all 0's
- checked X for columns whose values were identical

I removed one of each matching pair, so there are no longer duplicative columns. However, when I run `mnrfit`, although I get an output of coefficient estimates, I get this message for each column:

```
"Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND = 1.989093e-19 [differs for each col]."
```

I've searched, but haven't been able to figure out what this means. Also, the vector of coefficient estimates that's output contains a value at the top with a star next to it, and I don't know what this means. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that despite your cleaning your matrix is still of insufficient rank (this gives the singular warning).

Even after removing all obvious pairs, or single columns that only have 1 value, there may still be linear combinations.

This is easy to check with the [`rank`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/rank.html) command in Matlab. If the resulting number is less than your column amount you did not solve the problem.

---

To attack this problem, probably using [`rref`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/rref.html) on the matrix (or transposed matrix?) can help you identify which columns need to be eliminated.